# Figsize argument is ignored in drawing a barplot with Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, size, bar-chart

The following code produces the plot that is embedded but the argument that defines the size of the plot (figsize) is apparently ignored for reasons I do not understand.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))

ax = SP500_Growth_quantiles.plot(kind = 'bar')
ax.set_title('Quantiles of the Probability Distribution of S&P 500 Growth in 2018')
ax.set(ylabel = 'S&P 500 Growth in 2018', xlabel = 'Quantile')
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
SP500_Growth_quantiles.plot(kind = 'bar', ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Quantiles of the Probability Distribution of S&P 500 Growth in 2018')
ax.set(ylabel = 'S&P 500 Growth in 2018', xlabel = 'Quantile')
```